# How can I have varying speeds for my Motion gamelogic actuator?

Tags: game-engine

I wanted to walk and crouch walk. Walk with a faster speed and crouch walk with a slower speed. The control for the walk is <kbd>W</kbd> and crouch walk is <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but when I play the game, the crouch walk speed is the same as the walking speed. I don't want to change any of the controls, so is there any solution ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think that W key motion is overriding the W+C you should change the logic so the faster motion stop when you hold C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one away to do it :
Instead of having a low speed for the crouch give it a negative speed this way when it is combined with faster motion it slow it down

[image]

Comment: @XavierChoo does that solve it for you ?

Comment: Somehow , i feel like an idiot after looking at this xDD !Learn a lesson ! Think another way round haha! Thanks ... and just by looking at it , i know it will work without trying. Yes , it did work.